# Image is being fetched every time when I change the src of img element in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am trying to make an image display component which takes an array of image src and displays the images in a layout like shown below. But the problem is that when I click I'm changing the src of the image element, it is fetching the image again.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I prevent the image from refetching again?
The image must only be fetched on the first time.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have the cache disabled in your developer tools?

Comment: Yes, Oh my god how did I not notice that. 
Thank you so much. You saved my day.